# Is there a command line Ethereum client for vanilla Raspbian?

Tags: cli

Is there a command line Ethereum client for vanilla Raspbian?

Hello,

Is there a command line client for Ethereum such as Geth or Parity which would run on a vanilla Raspberry Pi 3 B? I.e I do not want to install a custom OS but rather use the normal Raspbian installed on this unit.

Vesa

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for ? [Pi-Gen](https://github.com/diglos/pi-gen)

> EthRaspbian is a custom Linux image for the Raspberry pi 2/3 that runs Geth or Parity Ethereum client as a boot service and automatically turns your Rasberrypi into an full Ethereum node.

**UPDATE**

I'm sorry, I re-read the question and saw your not looking for a custom img. Here's another [guide](http://raspnode.com/diyEthereumGeth.html) for what it's worth.